# Encryption and Decryption with aes-192-cbc algorithm. I am having challenges with the decryption aspect. The code encrypted but failed at decryption

Tags: node.js, encryption

My code base. Will appreciate any help to resolve this please.
I have tried everything possible but it still failed to decrypt. It always return   "error": "Decryption failed"
I really need to get this to work..Any help would be appreciated.
The encryption part is working fine...encrypting perfectly but the decrypt part is throwing error each time I made a decrypt request. I have tried every available methods or means I know of it kept returning error each time decrypt request is made.

```
// Create an initialization vector (IV)
const generateInitializationVector = () => {
  return crypto.randomBytes(16); // 16 bytes = 128 bits
};

// const key = 'MySecretKey';

// Encrypt the data
function encrypt(data, key) {
  // Set the secret key
  const iv = generateInitializationVector();
  const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-192-cbc', key, iv);
  let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex');
  encrypted += cipher.final('hex');
  return encrypted;
}

// Decrypt the data
function decrypt(data, key) {
  const iv = generateInitializationVector();
  console.log({iv})  
const decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-192-cbc', key, iv);
console.log({decipher})
  let decrypted = decipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8'); // Add 'hex' and 'utf8' encoding
console.log({decrypted})
  decrypted = decrypted + decipher.final('utf8');
  return decrypted;
}



// Convert key to a 24-byte Buffer using PBKDF2
function convertKey(keyHex) {
  const salt = crypto.randomBytes(16); // Generate a random salt
  const iterations = 100000; // Number of iterations
  const keyLength = 24; // Desired key length in bytes

  const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(keyHex, salt, iterations, keyLength, 'sha512');
  return key;
}

// Encryption route
cryptRouter.post('/encrypt', (req, res) => {
  try {
    let originalData = req.body.data;
    let keyHex = req.body.key;
    // originalData = 'Hello world'
    // keyHex= 'hello Secret'

    if (!originalData || !keyHex) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Data and key are required' });
    }

    const key = convertKey(keyHex); // Convert key to 24-byte Buffer
    const encryptedData = encrypt(originalData, key);
  // console.log(encryptedData);
    res.json({ encryptedData});
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error('Encryption error:', error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Encryption failed' });
  }
});

// Decryption route
cryptRouter.post('/decrypt', (req, res) => {
  try {
    const encryptedData = req.body.data;
    const keyHex = req.body.key;
    const ivHex = req.body.iv; // Extract IV from the request body

    if (!encryptedData || !keyHex || !ivHex) {
      return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Encrypted data, key, and IV are required' });
    }

    const key = convertKey(keyHex);
    const decryptedData = decrypt(encryptedData, key, ivHex);
    res.json({ decryptedData });
  } catch (catchError) {
    logger.error('Error in decryption route:', catchError);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
  }
});



module.exports = cryptRouter;
```

Comment: How do you know it is "encrypting perfectly"?

Comment: Already checked it out on Postman

Comment: Your code seems to be inconsistent, the `decrypt(data, key)` implementation has two parameters, while in the call the IV is passed as 3rd parameter: `decrypt(encryptedData, key, ivHex)`. Post a consistent code.

Comment: Furthermore, the IV generated during encryption is not stored anywhere, so it is not available during decryption. Usually, the (non-secret) IV and ciphertext are concatenated during encryption. During decryption, both portions are separated.

Comment: Thank you all. I have been able to rectify the problem. It happens I was generating a fresh initializationVector for each function differently. I had to generate it once while encrypting and save it in a variable so I can get to use it while decrypting by using Buffer.From() method. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all. I have been able to rectify the problem. It happens I was generating a fresh initializationVector for each function differently. I had to generate it once while encrypting and save it in a variable so I can get to use it while decrypting by using Buffer.From() method. Thanks